# Transliterate in PHP not working with whatever method i try

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to transliterate any 'weird' characters to ASCII to make clean urls, however, somehow none of the methods are working.

Example:

```
var_dump(transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove', "'étudie le français'"));
```

returns: bool(false)

**Urlify** from -> https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify
returns this error and/or filters out all characters with accents:

```
"preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 1"
```

**iconv**
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "étudie le français");
iconv fails with the following error:

"iconv(): Detected an illegal character"

Completely out of ideas, i have tried many different types of input text (french, swedish, danish etc), none seem to work with any method.

Running latest PHP 7.04, php-intl / iconv are installed.

Comment: have to ask, is your php file in UTF-8?

Comment: Eeek... I'm afraid that was the case. (urlify still does not work but the rest works fine..)

Comment: I know nothing about the library, but glad you got the rest working. ^^